# Which parallax library does HBO use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

http://www.hbogo.com/product-tour/

I see from their (minified) code that it uses a jQuery plugin that extends it with jQuery.fn.parallaxing, but I'm unable to locate any github projects that use .parallaxing.

Does anyone know what plugin they use? Or maybe it is proprietary? It is incredibly smooth, and all of my attempts to replicate something like that that attaches to the scrollbar have brought the browser to a crawl, so I'm trying to figure out what they do differently.

Comment: did you think of looking at source to find out??

Comment: @charlietfl I assume from the first sentence of the question, "I see from their (minified) code that it uses a jQuery plugin..." that, yes, the OP has tried looking at the source of the page.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes... it's minified/uglified and the only clue I could find was that it uses .parallaxing(). There are some source comment attributions, but not for that plugin, which makes me think it was developed in-house.

Comment: run it through [jsbeutifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), at least be able to get better clues

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the link to the beautifier. There is lots of domain stuff mixed into the parallaxing code, so it is almost surely in-house. I noticed that they did use -webkit-translate and -webkit-transform when available, so that may account for the difference in smoothness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that they developed it in-house, and is not a public plugin.